# Ruby on Rails Validation Uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in my ruby on rails assignment that will let users input their first name, middle name and last name. Now I want to validate each of them using uniqueness. Of course, if the first, middle and last name already exist, it cannot be created. But if the first name is the only one that has and existing match in the database and the middle and last name is different, it should be created. Another example is that if only the middle name has an existing match in the database and the other two are different. The problem is that if I use, validates :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, uniqueness: true, it will not cover the said conditions. Please help me

Comment: Names are not unique, so you are trying to build an erroneous assumption into your database.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `:scope` keyword

Try

```
validates :first_name, uniqueness: { scope: [:last_name, :middle_name] }
```

And refer to [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Comment: what condition is that? if the first name is the only one that has and existing match in the database and the middle and last name is different?

Comment: It should work both ways.
This are failing conditions `first_name == last_name == middle_name`